# Data structure to show postal code on selecting city

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, dictionary, data-structures, jvm

I have a table with three fields-

1. Postal code
2. City
3. Suburb

Each row has a unique combination of these three columns. On the front-end I have an address form where I want to show the list of postal codes when the user is typing the city name. Something like this-

[image: address type ahead]

The table has around 30,000 entries so I can't hit the database everytime the user adds an alphabet. I want to store the entire table in a data structure when the form page loads and then retrieve the relevant rows everytime an alphabet is added in the city box.

What is the data structure that I should use to save the entire table in the JVM when the page loads?

Comment: Can you clarify what software you are asking about. Do you have any code you have been working on that you can show us?

Comment: Java MVC. I will be making an AJAX call to the controller everytime the user adds an alphabet in city.

Comment: Can you clarify a little? "I can't hit the database" means you are just not querying the database or you are skipping the round trip to server altogether?

Comment: @AnandUndavia : I am loading the entire table in my JVM before anything even before the form pages is loaded so I won't be hitting the DB but still I will be hitting the server everytime an alphabet is added.

Comment: Since this needs to be turned into HTML, I suggest saving a String which contains the HTML you need to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a Hash Map with keys as city names, and values as a string concatenating all the three fields (which is ultimately what has to be sent to the browser)

This map can be pre populated at startup

Comment: exactly what I was thinking.....although the keys would be every possible substring from the city and yes the value will be a concatenation of all three values....

Comment: Keys shouldn't be every possible substring as that would diminish the advantage of using hashing. Instead, maybe the better option would be to use contains method of string class

Comment: But then I have to compare the string that I get from the form with all the 30,000 rows of the table. WIth substring, I can get the corresponding address in O(1).

Comment: Ok. So, to decrease the the number of keys, perhaps we can use the use a hashcode function that returns the same value irrespective of the ordering of the substring. Thus, "ABC" will return the same bucket as "BAC", and the bucket will then be (automatically) traversed to get the exact key.

Comment: The main advantage would be a drastic reduction in the number of substrings that would serve as keys for the HashMap.. all that would be required will be a rewriting of the hash code function. This can be achieved (as I took from another SO answer) by ordering the input characters in the hashcode, and then returning the hashcode of the ordered string.